# Trouble with FlashVars in AS3 + flixel

Tags: actionscript-3, root, flashvars, flixel

I'm building my first flixel app (a flash-based game engine) and I'm having trouble accessing the FlashVars from my html source. Flixel's root element is not derived from the top-level root, and I can't get a workaround in place. I've done some research and found a few promising solution here:

http://forums.flixel.org/index.php/topic,449.msg3101.html#msg3101

however none of these solutions have worked for me. I think the magicRoot implementation is the best offered there, but I still haven't been able to get it working properly. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

You can get a reference to the stage from within a Flixel game by using `FlxG.stage`.

Comment: THANK YOU! this was a life saver!

Comment: What I ended up doing was putting this in my play state's constructor:

var params:Object = LoaderInfo(FlxG.stage.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
if(params.myParam != null)
 FlxG.switchState(new AnotherState(params.myParam));

And it worked like a charm! Hope this helps someone else, I had a hard time trying to figure this one out.